Decoding jpeg images with ICC metadata
There are several jpeg decoders like ijg, libjpeg-turbo, mini jpeg decoder, ... Assuming that the encoded jpeg file internal color format is YCbCr, to produce the final RGB image, the decoders have to do color space conversion. All these decoders are using the equations given in https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf even if the ICC block of jpeg image is indicating otherwise. What is the reason behind this?

It is mostly a historical accident. The original JPEG standard in 1992 evolved from code that was circulating in the late 1980's that happened to use those reference equations for YCrCb conversion to and from RGB space. Digital images were still quite rare and exotic back then and colour ones rarer still.
The colour management module aka CMM was essentially a bolt on for an already widely distributed code base that did JPEG encoding on that original basis. It's main feature was to be manufacturer independent and allow different capture and display devices to reproduce colour fidelity and dynamic range more accurately.
This answer on the photography stack exchange appears to answer most of your question. Various links to standards are available.
The ICC even has a website with more on it than you ever need to know. The FAQs are probably what you want for this.
The online reference site for JPEG also has details of the evolution of the standard to incorporate full colour management. Bearing in mind here the decoders and particularly those in web browsers were inclined to take shortcuts to get faster image rendering on what were the slow machines of that era.
It wasn't until the ICC 3.0 standard in 1994/5 for profile 2.0.0 that colour management became a thing as users like graphics designers who cared about colour fidelity started to use digital images. By then there were quite  lot of digital images around (but nothing compared to how ubiquitous they have become today). APP2 markers were used to tack the profile into JPEG with a key "ICC_PROFILE" see this previous answer for details.
To put it into perspective the Kodak DC120 consumer grade 1 megapixel (marketing speak it was slightly upsampled to get there) came out in 1997. Prior to that professional digital cameras were available but $$$$. I can't recall if it did embed a colour profile in its JPEGs or not - it also had the option to save raw Bayer and post process in a slower higher fidelity external software. Back then things were less standardised and more proprietory with competing digital formats like Kodak's PCD digital scanning format for film to digital image.

JPEG images are commonly stored using the YCbCr color space. Cb and Cr represent the chrominance (color information). JPEG decoder must convert the YCbCr data to RGB. And its possible with complex equations.
Not all JPEG decoders support ICC profiles, especially older or simpler implementations. If ICC profile is missing decoders will fall back to the stndard conversion equations to ensure the image can still be rendered correctly.
Do your research on ICC, it has deeper context which you need to be grinding on.
